# How do I make calls to a struts 2 action form using JQuery or javascript and/or json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, forms, struts2

I need to update a form based on some entries that are taken from the user (present in the same form). This allows me to have a single add update page.

2 parameters accepted from the user need to be sent to a struts 2 action. A DB query executed inside the action returns a data set. This data set needs to be sent back to the UI and the UI needs to be updated.

Please help.

Comment: So you want a single add and update page for a user? What is the DB query? I can present a solution of a single add and update user page using Hibernate, but I don't know if that is what you're searching for.

Comment: Just saw that you wanted to use JavaScript to make the page, don't have a solution ready for that anyways, sorry.

Comment: I am doing well with jquery now. any of $.post or $.ajax would work. $.json is used specifically to extract json data which again is a asynchronous call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [jQuery's .post() method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). The results can be JSON or HTML and handled appropriately.

```
$.post({
    theUrl,
    { field1: "value", field2: "value" },
    function(data) { $("#resultsDiv").html(data)
});
```

If you need more control, you can use the [.ajax function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

There are a variety of ways to get an S2 URL into the arguments, including just having the JavaScript in the JSP page and using the tag, having the `$.post` call itself in an external JS and calling in from the JSP page passing the URL in, processing your JS files with the JSP processor, and so on.

There are also at least two jQuery plugins that can wrap this up into a tag, but IMO it's easier and cleaner to just do it using "raw" jQuery.

Comment: @Arvind Which is why I mentioned it ;)